# How do I maintain values between spring task scheduled

Tags: java, spring, cron, spring-batch

I want to maintain values between the spring task:scheduled, example my cron is to trigger every one hour.

```
<task:scheduled-tasks>
<task:scheduled ref="runScheduler" method="run" cron="0 0 * * * *" />
</task:scheduled-tasks>
```

I want to know, How do I get the value from last hour cron thread on next cron thread.

Answer (score 0):

Cron attribute is used with @Scheduled annotation. Value of this attribute must be a cron expression.This cron expression will be defined in a properties file and key of related property will be used in @Scheduled annotation.

```
<task:scheduled-tasks>
<task:scheduled ref="runScheduler" method="run" cron="#{applicationProps['cron.expression']}" />
</task:scheduled-tasks>
```

Then use @Scheduled(cron = "${cron.expression}") annotation.

Following link might help you:

http://howtodoinjava.com/spring/spring-core/4-ways-to-schedule-tasks-in-spring-3-scheduled-example/

Comment: My clarification is, Lets say as per cron the job triggered at 9.00 AM and holding some value and next job is at 10.00 AM and want to get the value of 9.00 AM job in 10.00 AM job. How can I do this ?